# Cascading Drop Down in ASP.NET Core using Razor and jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been trying to populate two dropdown list from my database. The first one is populated on form load, and I want to fill the second after the user selects a value in the first one.

I have followed and adapted [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/) tutorial. But with no luck.

My Controller

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using MaterialProjectMaterials.Models;
using UserProfile.Models;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MaterialProject.Controllers
{
    public class MaterialsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(GetConString.ConString());

        public IActionResult Materials()
        {
            List<Brands> brandslist = new List<Brands>();
            brandslist.Insert(0, new Brands { BCodeID = 0, BDescr = "--Select Brand--" });
            //Getting Data from Database using EntityFrameworkCore
            con.Open();
            string b_query = "SELECT codeID, descr  FROM itemcategory WHERE codeID LIKE ('3%') AND LENGTH(codeID)= 3 and rownum<=2 ORDER BY descr";
            OracleCommand b_cmd = new OracleCommand(b_query, con);
            OracleDataAdapter b_da = new OracleDataAdapter(b_cmd);
            DataTable b_dt = new DataTable();
            b_da.Fill(b_dt);
            foreach (DataRow b_rb in b_dt.Rows)
            {
                brandslist.Add(new Brands
                {
                    BCodeID = Convert.ToInt64(b_rb["codeID"]),
                    BDescr = b_rb["descr"].ToString()
                });
            }
            con.Close();
            ViewBag.BrandsList = brandslist;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Materials(Brands objbrand, FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            //Validation
            if (objbrand.BCodeID == 0)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Select Brand");
            else if (objbrand.VCodeID == 0)
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Select Volume");

            //Getting selected Value
            var BCodeID = HttpContext.Request.Form["BCodeID"].ToString();
            var VCodeID = HttpContext.Request.Form["VCodeID"].ToString();

            //Setting Data back to ViewBag after Posting Form
            List<Brands> brandslist = new List<Brands>();
            brandslist.Insert(0, new Brands { BCodeID = 0, BDescr = "--Select Brand--" });
            //Getting Data from Database
            con.Open();
            string b_query = "SELECT codeID, descr  FROM itemcategory WHERE codeID LIKE ('3%') AND LENGTH(codeID)= 3 ORDER BY descr";
            OracleCommand b_cmd = new OracleCommand(b_query, con);
            OracleDataAdapter b_da = new OracleDataAdapter(b_cmd);
            DataTable b_dt = new DataTable();
            b_da.Fill(b_dt);
            foreach (DataRow b_rb in b_dt.Rows)
            {
                brandslist.Add(new Brands
                {
                    BCodeID = Convert.ToInt64(b_rb["codeID"]),
                    BDescr = b_rb["descr"].ToString()
                });
            }
            con.Close();
            //Assing BCodeID to ViewBag.BrandsList
            ViewBag.BrandsList = brandslist;
            return View(objbrand); 
        }

        public JsonResult GetVolumes(Int64? BCodeID)
        {
            if (BCodeID == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(BCodeID));
            }

            List<Volume> volumelist = new List<Volume>();
            volumelist.Insert(0, new Volume { VCodeID = 0, VDescr = "--Select Volume--" });
            //Getting Data from Database
            con.Open();
            string v_query = "SELECT DISTINCT IG.CODEID, IG.DESCR FROM MATERIAL M INNER JOIN ITEMGROUP IG ON M.IGPID = IG.CODEID INNER JOIN ITEMCATEGORY IC ON '3' || SUBSTR(M.ICTID, 3, 2) = IC.CODEID WHERE M.ICTID LIKE('3%') AND IC.CODEID =" + BCodeID + "ORDER BY CODEID";
            OracleCommand v_cmd = new OracleCommand(v_query, con);
            OracleDataAdapter v_da = new OracleDataAdapter(v_cmd);
            DataTable v_dt = new DataTable();
            v_da.Fill(v_dt);
            foreach (DataRow v_dr in v_dt.Rows)
            {
                volumelist.Add(new Volume
                {
                    VCodeID = Convert.ToInt64(v_dr["codeID"]),
                    VDescr = v_dr["descr"].ToString()
                });
            }
            con.Close();
            return Json(new SelectList(volumelist, "VCodeID", "VDescr"));
        }
    }
}
```

My View

```
@model MaterialProjectMaterials.Models.Brands
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

@{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var items = "<option value='0'>--Select Volume--</option>";
            $("VCodeID").html(items);
        });
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#BCodeID").change(function () {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Materials/GetVolumes";
                var ddlsource = "#BCodeID";
                $.getJSON(url, { BCodeID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) {
                    var items = '';
                    $("#VCodeID").empty();
                    $.each(data, function (i, volume) {
                        items += "<option value='" + volume.value + "'>" + volume.text + "</option>";
                    });
                    $("#VCodeID").html(items);
                });
            })
        })
    </script>

    <form asp-controller="Materials" asp-action="Materials" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="alert-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <label asp-for="BDescr" class="control-label">Brands</label>
                    <select asp-for="BCodeID" class="form-control"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.BrandsList, "BCodeID", "BDescr"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Volume</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="vCodeID" name="vDescr" asp-for="VCodeID"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "VCodeID", "VDescr"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
}
```

My Models

```cs
namespace MaterialProjectMaterials.Models
{

    public class MaterialsModel
    { 
        public DbSet<Brands> Brands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Volume> Volume { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MaterialProjectMaterials.Models
{
    [Table("ITEMCATEGORY")]
    public class Brands
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("CODEID")]
        public Int64 BCodeID { get; set; }
        [Column("DESCR")]
        public string BDescr { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public Int64 VCodeID { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MaterialProjectMaterials.Models
{
    [Table("IT_MATERIAL_VOLUMES")]
    public class Volume
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("VCODEID")]
        public Int64 VCodeID { get; set; }
        [Column("VDESCR")]
        public string VDescr { get; set; }
        [Column("BDESCR")]
        public int BCodeID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The result when I run the project is that I can get the values in the first dropdownlist, but when I select a value I did not get anything back to the second dropdownlist.

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=" + BCodeID + "ORDER` will give a SQL error as it needs a space before "ORDER BY"

Comment: Thanks for noticing this one out, but still the second ddl doesn't fill with values.
I tent to believe that I have mess up something with js scripts and they don't work at all. Because when I ran the project and load the form the default value in the second ddl would be "--Select Volume--" from the
```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var items = "<option value='0'>--Select Volume--</option>";
            $("VCodeID").html(items);
        });
    </script>
```
but the ddl is totally empty.

Comment: Forget about filling the values at first.  The fact that your MVC action had a blatant error but you're only looking at the end goal indicates you need to take a few steps back to find out what's going.  First : `$.getJSON(url, { BCodeID: $(ddlsource).val() }, function (data) { console.log(data); console.log(data.length, data[0].value, data[0].text)); });` - do you get expected data?  Is it actually an `array` (as expected by your JS) or is, as your action indicates, a `SelectList`?   Does the data have properties `.text` or, more likely `.Text` (as it's a SelectList).

Comment: If you `return Json(new SelectList(volumelist, "VCodeID", "VDescr"))` then in the js, at a minimum you'd need to use `volume.Value` (not `volume.value`) - which indicates you're not looking at what's coming back.

Comment: Thanks again for the insight, I'm very new to ASP.NET Core and js. I have added the code you send for the log I didn't get nothing back. I also use volume.Value and volume.Text but still nothing.
I get 2 message for MaterialsController.cs,
1 in the [HttpPost]
public IActionResult Materials(Brands objbrand, IFormCollection formCollection)
it says "Remove unused parameter 'formCollection' if it is not part of a shipped public API"
and
2. at the same function 9 row below, it says
"Value assigned to 'VCodeID' is never used"

I don't know if those can help you understand the problem.

Comment: I actually solved the above 2 message warnings but still I can't fill the second drop down list. Solution for 1. I add in the function body the line _=formCollection; and for 2. It really was a variable that I didn't use because is for future implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update 1 
In the debugger I get the follows error concerning the javascrips

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44373/lib/jquery/jquery.js  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 3.5252ms 404 
Unhandled exception at line 4, column 9 in https://localhost:44373/Home/Login
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined
```

as for the line

```
Unhandled exception at line 4, column 9 in https://localhost:44373/Home/Login
```

it says that the script locate at ~/Home/Login but my script are at ~/Materials/Materials
Finally my .js files are locate at
~\MaterialProject\wwwroot\lib\jquery
Any help would appreciate a lot!
Update 2 
**I solve my problem**
I use  instead of  and also I replace

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <label class="control-label">Volume</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="vCodeID" name="vDescr" asp-for="VCodeID"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "VCodeID", "VDescr"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

with

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                    <label asp-for="VDescr" class="control-label">Volume</label>
                    <select asp-for="VCodeID" class="form-control"
                            asp-items="@(new SelectList(string.Empty, "VCodeID", "VDescr"))"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```